# CakePHP Routing help

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have the following link: `<?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Portfolio']['title'],
        array('controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'view', Tiny::toTiny($post['Portfolio']['id']), Inflector::slug($post['Portfolio']['title'])),
        array('title' => $post['Portfolio']['title'])); ?>`

which creates urls like `http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/view/3z/Paperview_Magazine`

BUT I want to remove the `view` part of the url via the routing system. So far I have implemented this:

`Router::connect('/portfolio/id:/slug:', array('controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'view', 'id', 'slug'));`

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
Router::connect('/portfolio/*', array('controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'view'));
```

Comment: Thanks mate. You are becoming a legend tonight ;)